# laravel wherebetween in relations not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables in mysql, 1. Vehicles and 2.Locations
i am using eloquent relations to define relation of the vehicle table to locations.

here is how my vehicles modle looks.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class VehicleModel extends Model {
function locations(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\locations", "vehicle_id", "id");
    }
}
```

i am trying to run a query that can get me locations of specific vehicle between two given times.

here is what i am trying to do:

```
App\VehicleModel::find(3)->location->whereBetween('locations.time', $range);
```

I was expecting to above query would give me locations between dates which it does when i run without the relation. but when when i do run in a relation i am getting an unexpeted error.

**PHP error:  Call to a member function whereHas() on null on line 1**

Please help me see where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to:

```
App\VehicleModel::find(3)->locations()->whereBetween('time', $range)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using relationship method without parenthesis return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections), use parenthesis to return the relationship where you can add other query methods like whereBetween:

```
App\VehicleModel::find(3)->location()->whereBetween('time', $range)->get();
```

Comment: This will return a relationship instance.

Comment: add `->get()` at the end to fetch the data

Answer (score 1):

you send query from other relation model `location`

your query look like this `location->location`

please check this code

```
App\VehicleModel::find(3)->locations()->whereBetween('time', $range);
```

Comment: This will return a relationship instance. Also, you're using the wrong relationship.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i updated my code.  I forgot brackets

Comment: You also need to add `get()` to execute the query.