# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::shipment_batch()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have 2 tables `shipments` and `shipment_batches` on shipment contains `shipment_batch_id` foreign key for `shipment_batches`. In `shipment_batches` there is a column `shipment_date`.

in my shipment model i have this relationship

```
public function shipment_batch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ShipmentBatch::class, 'shipment_batch_id');
}
```

now i want to filter and display all shipments base on `shipment_date` in `shipment_batches` with this.

```
$from   = $this->_filters['shipment_batch_shipment_date']["'from'"];
$to     = $this->_filters['shipment_batch_shipment_date']["'to'"];

$model = $model->shipment_batch();
$model = $model->whereBetween('shipment_date', [$from, $to]);
```

but got badmethodexception saying

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::shipment_batch()
```

Where I've been wrong?
What to is the right thing to do?

I trying to follow this as reference

[laravel wherebetween in relations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156429/laravel-wherebetween-in-relations-not-working)

Comment: What is `$model` set to right before this snippet of code?

Comment: `["'from'"]` and `["'to'"]` Two sets of quotes? That's unnecessary. Just use one or the other. Also, `$model = $model::shipment_batch();` is `$model` defined elsewhere?

Comment: shipment...............

Comment: You wouldn't ever call a relationship method statically.  Did you read the querying relationships part of the docs?

Comment: ["'from'"] and ["'to'"] is correct.. even using debugger.. is using 'from' and 'to' as string index in array

Comment: `["'from'"]` yeah it works, but it's redundant; `["from"]` and `['from']` are both normal and accepted, but `["'from'"]` is just... Weird.

Comment: @devon sorry, I just tried that, the first thing I did was using ->

Comment: @TimLewis yeah but that there it is.. using datatable  https://datatables.yajrabox.com/

Comment: I have no idea what `["'from'"]` has to do with datatables... But whatever; it was advice to make your code more readable. It's not the core of your issue, so ignore it. What is `$model`? Run a `dd(get_class($model));` to see if it's a `shipment` model or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) to query relations, or [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to eager load relationships.  It appears you just want Shipments with a specific batch date, so you wouldn't need to load the relationship, just query it.  An example being:

```
Shipment::whereHas('shipment_batch', function($q) {
    $from   = $this->_filters['shipment_batch_shipment_date']["'from'"];
    $to     = $this->_filters['shipment_batch_shipment_date']["'to'"];
    $q->whereBetween('shipment_date', [$from, $to]);
});
```

Comment: I first try it never worked.. but then i realized that a mistake is that the `shipment_batch_id` should have a value that match the shipment_batches ID. Your solution is helpful.. thanks